# laravel local storage 404 error on images

Tags: laravel

I have made a youtube style website, some people may click the video to be private, I keep these videos in storage/app/vidoes/{channelname}, the public images and videos I have working not a problem but local storage I am having a problem with, any ideas?

just getting a 404 on the thumbnails

thanks

view

```
 <img src="{{ route('home.image', ['file_path' => 'videos/'  . $video->channel_name  . '/thumbnails/' . $video->video_thumbnail_name]) }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
```

route

```
Route::get('{file_path}', [
        'uses' => 'HomeController@getImage',
        'as' => 'home.image'
]);
```

controller

```
public function getImage($filepath)
{

    $fileContents = \Storage::disk('local')->get($filepath);

    $response = \Response::make($fileContents, 200);

    $response->header('Content-Type', "image/jpg");

    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Laravel 5.8 local storage working for images

view

```
 <img class="home-video" src="{{ route('getImage', ['thumbnail' => $video->video_thumbnail_name, 'channel_name' => $video->channel_name]) }}" alt="" >
```

Route

```
Route::get('get-image/{channel_name}/{thumbnail}','HomeController@getImage')->name('getImage');
```

Controller

> ```
> public function getImage($channel_name,$thumbnail)
> {
>
>     $fileContents = \Storage::disk('local')->get("videos/$channel_name/thumbnails/$thumbnail");
>
>     return \Image::make($fileContents)->response();
>
> }
> ```

see how the thumbnail is important for me, I was passing the thumbnail name eg photo.jpg if you are using route model binding you would want to pass the id of the image, hope this saves someone a few hours